# producing lot of heat and fan sound, while using ubuntu 12.04 on dell xps-l502x

Tags: dell, overheating, xps

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my XPS L502. Everything works fine except the system heat. I can feel that the laptop heat rises more and fan sound also, when I am using ubuntu. But with Windows 7 that came pre-installed with laptop heat is normal. I like to use Ubuntu on this laptop, but because of this reason I am not able to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by installing Bumblebee.

It seems like it was a problem with power management. After installing Bumblebee and restarting my computer, it ran smoothly, with quiet fan and at normal temperature. Actually, now my battery last longer in Ubuntu than it does on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [cpufrequtils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/cpufrequtils) to reduce the CPU frequency or [cpufreqd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/cpufreqd) to adjust that frequency depending on system load, active processes, temperature and so on. In case that `cpufreq-info` from cpufrequtils reports the governor `ondemand` and high frequencies, you might want to use [top](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/top.1.html) to see where that demand comes from, i.e. which processes keep the CPU busy.

Comment: by this how can i reduce the head and fan sound...

Comment: The lower the frequency of your CPU cores, the less power it consumes, the less heat it generates.

Comment: I installed Bumblebee and now the cpu frequency reduced and it solved the heat generation problem.Thanks...