# overheating processors - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, overheating

I have an hp pavilion dv4 , and i have many problems with the hardware of the machine and the software.

Here I describe the BIOS information

```
ACPI 2.0 present.
 OEM Identifier: HPQOEM
 RSD Table 32-bit Address: 0xACFFE0AC
 XSD Table 64-bit Address: 0x00000000ACFFE120
PNP BIOS 1.0 present.
 Event Notification: Not Supported
 Real Mode 16-bit Code Address: F000:B884
 Real Mode 16-bit Data Address: 0040:0000
 16-bit Protected Mode Code Address: 0x000FB88F
 16-bit Protected Mode Data Address: 0x00000400
 OEM Device Identifier: SST2400
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
 Structure Table Length: 1901 bytes
 Structure Table Address: 0x000E6830
 Number Of Structures: 39
 Maximum Structure Size: 162 bytes
BIOS32 Service Directory present.
 Revision: 0
 Calling Interface Address: 0x000EF725
PCI Interrupt Routing 1.0 present.
 Router ID: 00:1f.0
 Exclusive IRQs: None
 Compatible Router: 8086:122e
 Slot Entry 1: ID 00:01, on-board
 Slot Entry 2: ID 00:02, on-board
 Slot Entry 3: ID 00:04, on-board
 Slot Entry 4: ID 00:06, on-board
 Slot Entry 5: ID 01:00, on-board
 Slot Entry 6: ID 02:00, on-board
 Slot Entry 7: ID 08:00, on-board
 Slot Entry 8: ID 00:16, on-board
 Slot Entry 9: ID 00:18, on-board
 Slot Entry 10: ID 00:19, on-board
 Slot Entry 11: ID 00:1a, on-board
 Slot Entry 12: ID 00:1b, on-board
 Slot Entry 13: ID 00:1c, on-board
 Slot Entry 14: ID 00:1d, on-board
 Slot Entry 15: ID 00:1f, on-board
```

The information of hardware:

```
producto: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
             producto: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       producto: 3585
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             producto: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
                producto: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
             producto: BDDVDRW CT30L
                producto: Centrino Wireless-N 1030
             producto: HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
    producto: HP Pavilion dv4 Notebook PC (LY917LA#ABM)
          producto: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
             producto: M471B5273DH0-CH9
       producto: MU06055
       producto: OEM_Define5
             producto: SAMSUNG HM641JI
                producto: SD/MMC Host Controller
                producto: Standard SD Host Controller

descripción: **VGA compatible controller**
       producto: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 2
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versión: 09
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuración: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:42 memoria:c0000000-c03fffff memoria:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.10
Release: 12.10
Codename: quantal
```

My problem is that processors overheat all time. Temperature between 60 ° C and 85 ° C, with few programs operating.

With Windows the machine doesn't overheat.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with my Lenovo T500 and Ubuntu 12.04. The only release that was working for me was 10.04. With that my laptop didn't overheat. Since that time I have always problems. It doesn't help not even jupiter or indicator-cpufreq. Problem is that is not overheating just the processor but entire laptop. When I have Windows running, my laptop is much more cooler. My opinion is that there is still some problems with kernel. The only solution for me was to put AC - powersave mode in BIOS. But this solves just the temp of processor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [cpufrequtils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/cpufrequtils) to reduce the CPU frequency, specifically by setting the governor to `ondemand`.

See also:

- [producing lot of heat and fan sound, while using ubuntu 12.04 on dell xps-l502x](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156366/producing-lot-of-heat-and-fan-sound-while-using-ubuntu-12-04-on-dell-xps-l502x/156371#156371)